# Android design advice - services & broadcast receivers

Tags: design-patterns, android, android-development

I'm in the process of learning the Android SDK and creating some projects to get a grasp on the system.  The current project I'm working with works just fine but I'd like to get some advice about other ways I can go about designing it.

Here's what it needs to do.
When a text message is received from a specific number, it should fire off a toast message that repeats at a certain interval for a specific duration.

1. To make this work, I created an SMS BroadcastReceiver and checked the incoming messages for the number I'm looking for.
2. If found, an IntentService would be started that would pull out the interval and duration from saved shared prefs.  The IntentService would then fire off a broadcast.
3. The BroadcastReceiver for this would catch it and use the AlarmManager to handle the toast message repetitions.

This all works just fine, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner or more efficient way of going about doing this? 
Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: You can use a handler and then display a toast on the ui thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your first 2 pieces are correct. While you *could* combine steps 1 & 2 into a single step by doing everything in the broadcast receiver - but you don't want to do that. The biggest difference between a BroadcastReceiver and an IntentService is that Broadcast Receiver's run on the main thread. This means that you want to spend as little time in them as you can. That makes it a pretty good idea to follow the pattern of receiving a message in the receiver and then dispatching a message to an IntentService where work can be done off of the main thread.

Where I would change my approach to your problem is steps 2-3... I would do the work of setting up the first (or next) alarm in the IntentService or not, depending on your business logic (i.e. user disabled the alarm some how). I would then use Handler.PostDelayed to start the same IntentService - again - at some point in the future.

Also - using toasts is one option - but I would also consider using a notification in addition to the toast (or maybe instead of)... that would provide a convenient means of allowing the user to respond to the alarm condition.